# Unable to run the jarvis1.exe file created from jarvis1.py using pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, pyttsx3

Python version is 3.10 and pyinstaller is 4.7

I converted jarvis1.py into jarvis1.exe using `pyinstaller --onefile jarvis1.py` command.

But when I run the exe file , this error flashes for a second and then it ends.
[image: Traceback]

I have also added the hidden imports as per this [discussion](https://github.com/nateshmbhat/pyttsx3/issues/6).

Here's my jarvis1.spec file after building:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-


block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['jarvis1.py'],
             pathex=[],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=['pyttsx3.drivers','pyttsx3.drivers.dummy','pyttsx3.drivers.espeak','pyttsx3.drivers.nsss','pyttsx3.drivers.sapi5'],
             hookspath=[],
             hooksconfig={},
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,  
          [],
          name='jarvis1',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True,
          disable_windowed_traceback=False,
          target_arch=None,
          codesign_identity=None,
          entitlements_file=None )
```

Help me run the exe file.

Comment: You should add a [minimal reproducible version](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of jarvis1.py to your question.

Comment: Also you should include the [error message as text rather than an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: Even capturing the screenshot was difficult... Like i said on running the exe file , it just opened for a second ,I couldn't copy the error message in that.